# How to call php script in html page to display php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have php script i want to call its variable in html page either using jquery/javascript/ajax . plz help me the script is here

```
<?php
$sta = $matches[1];
$tm = $matches[2];
$c = $matches[3];
$v= $matches[4];
$a1= $matches[5];
$a2= $matches[6];
$a3= $matches[7];
$a4= $matches[8];
$a5= $matches[9];
$a6= $matches[10];
$a11= $matches[11];
$a12= $matches[12];
$a13= $matches[13];
$a14= $matches[14];
$a15=$matches[15];
$a16= $matches[16];
$a17= $matches[17];
$a18= $matches[18];
$a19= $matches[19];
?>
```

Comment: The only way to do that would be to print the PHP variables as a javascript variable in the HTML.  Or to make a remote call to the PHP Script for the value.  Once the PHP script has executed it's no longer "around" or running for something to "access".

Comment: If this is the whole script, please also be aware that variables are not retained between different HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible , you can just use ajax script that load the php script return content in html element .